# Mount shared Windows 10 folder on virtual machine VMware Linux CentOS mount error(13): Permission Denied

Tags: linux, windows-10, centos, vmware

I am trying to mount a shared folder from Windows 10 to a VMware virtual machine Linux CentOS with this command:

```
mount -t cifs //ip/folder /mnt/win -o 
username=xxx,password=xxx,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,uid=root
```

However, I keep receiving this error:

> mount error(13): Permission denied